# What to do to get grub multiple booting?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

There is Win7 and ubuntu11.10 and i want to install kubuntu also (64bit). I have started installation on a separate partition and decided to install grub on this and not on boot-one, where it still is. In the mid of the process i stopped, because two grubs are not working,i guess. But the question of the installer was not to add a new system, instead to install grub (new i guess).

- Does this mean it will find automatically my old two systems or will i have trouble to add those again?
- Has somebody done it, working with chosing all three + options?

Also there are now some kubuntu files in my /home on another partition, seems to be damaged, because i cannot delete them, also in /usr/share. They are perhaps from installing an iso of kubuntu on CD, which works, but not fine. The boot screen is not to read, with "enter" it starts.

So two questions:

1. What does grub really do, while "installed"?
2. How to delete a damaged empty file, which seems to be only the icon. I have no right to delete, because it is not there or doesn´t exist, is only to see.

Strange, isn´t it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easiest to go with the defaults and install grub to the MBR as you install Kubuntu. When you do so all 3 OS should show in the grub boot menu and you will be able to select which OS to boot.

By default, the grub menu may be hidden, if that is the case hold down the shift button as you boot.

See [The Ubuntu Wiki grub page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring_GRUB_2) for information on how to configure grub.

Alternately you can install kubuntu, then boot your old Ubuntu install and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

should recognize kubuntu.

Comment: Sounds good, but you tell boot ubuntu. My fear is, that there will be nothing to boot, so have you tried it really?

Comment: Why would there be nothing to boot ? When installing a operating system it is important to understand partitions and where you are installing to. You should back up your data as occasionally there are problems. With that in mind the installer is designed to work extremely well with the default settings and you should not change them unless you understand what you are doing and how to manually debug any problems you might encounter. On my netbook I have 4 OS installed (gentoo, fedora, ubuntu, and an older version of ubuntu), and on my laptop I currently have 3 (Windows XP?, Ubuntu, and Fedora.

Comment: Well thanks, i used only default settings, one option is to install grub not at the boot-partition. Sometimes windows make trouble there. Grub isn´t at MBR, there is only a link. I will do install again.

Comment: Now i have two grubs, one not working from ubuntu, even after "update-grub" and a new working from kubuntu. Before i had run Paragon partition manager to shift win-partions a little, because ubuntu manager told " bad performance, misaligning". Afterwards nothing was possible, grub destroyed. I then installed kubuntu and thought, grub will find the other OS, easy. But it found only the corrupt one and i have had 3 OS with

Comment: no one booting. This little "beta" grub repair file restored the kubuntu grub at MBR. The ubuntu one sits on boot-sda of ubuntu. So it is working now.